# Ruby Sequel AS/400 connection issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, odbc, ibm-midrange

I need to connect to a AS/400 system using ODBC connection, and I'm using the Ruby [sequel gem](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/). My environment is just Ubuntu 14.04 running in virtual box. I'm able to run `isql -v my.host.com` and drop in to a sql console. When I try and do this from IRB, I get the error message.

```
require 'sequel'
db = Sequel.odbc(:drvconnect=>'driver={IBM i Access ODBC Driver};system=my.host.com;database=MYDBNAME;uid=MYUSERNAME;password=MYPASSWORD;DefaultLibraries=, *usrlibl;authentication=server')
tables = db[:QSYS2__SYSTABLES].where("TABLE_NAME like ?", "SYS%")
tables.each do |record|
  puts record[:table_name]
end

#=> Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: ODBC::Error: IM002 (0) [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.32.0/lib/sequel/adapters/odbc.rb:21:in `drvconnect'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.32.0/lib/sequel/adapters/odbc.rb:21:in `connect'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.32.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:103:in `make_new'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.32.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:224:in `make_new'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.32.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:197:in `available'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.32.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:133:in `_acquire'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.32.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:147:in `block in acquire'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.32.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:265:in `block in sync'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.32.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:265:in `synchronize'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.32.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:265:in `sync'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.32.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:146:in `acquire'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.32.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:104:in `hold'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.32.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:251:in `synchronize'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.32.0/lib/sequel/adapters/odbc.rb:44:in `execute'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.32.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:952:in `execute'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.32.0/lib/sequel/adapters/odbc.rb:97:in `fetch_rows'
from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.32.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:141:in `each'
```

I'm not familiar at all with AS/400 or using ODBC connections, but if `isql` works then maybe it's a user permission error?

Here is my `/etc/odbc.ini`

```
[my.host.com]
Description = IBM i Access ODBC Driver
Driver      = IBM i Access ODBC Driver
System      = my.host.com
UserID      = MYUSERNAME
Password    = MYPASSWORD
Naming      = 1
DefaultLibraries = *usrlibl;
Database    = MYDBNAME
```

I should also mention that the AS/400 system is located remotely at the `my.host.com`, so I'm not trying to connect to some local running service. I am able to ping the IP address of that host though.

**Edit**: I've changed my driver in the drvconnect to match what's in the `odbc.ini` as per the suggestion below. Also I should note that I have a `/etc/odbcinst.ini` file with the following

```
[IBM i Access ODBC Driver]
Description     = IBM i Access for Linux ODBC Driver
Driver      = /opt/ibm/iaccess/lib/libcwbodbc.so
Setup       = /opt/ibm/iaccess/lib/libcwbodbcs.so
Driver64        = /opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
Setup64     = /opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbodbcs.so
Threading       = 0
DontDLClose     = 1
UsageCount      = 1

[IBM i Access ODBC Driver 64-bit]
Description     = IBM i Access for Linux 64-bit ODBC Driver
Driver      = /opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
Setup       = /opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbodbcs.so
Threading       = 0
DontDLClose     = 1
UsageCount      = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
require 'sequel'
db = Sequel.odbc(:drvconnect=>'driver={iSeries Access ODBC Driver}; system=my.host.com;...
```

But then you show this:

```
[my.host.com]
Description = IBM i Access ODBC Driver
Driver      = IBM i Access ODBC Driver
```

If you actually have the **IBM i Access ODBC Driver**, Then that's what you should reference in your code, rather than **iSeries Access ODBC Driver**.

Comment: That makes sense. I've been tasked with porting this app from PHP over to rails, and this connection string and that odbc.ini are exactly what the PHP app uses. This app is a mess, so it's possible it only uses one over the other. I tried that, and still get the same error. I'll update my example. Thanks

Comment: Could be other issues. That just jumped out on first glance. More info in the question can help. DB2 OS version? DB2 group PTF level on server? System i Access service level on client?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! It turns out that when you have your `/etc/odbc.ini` defined with all your connection info, you don't need a connection string.

```
require 'sequel'
db = Sequel.odbc(drvconnect: '')
tables = db[:QSYS2__SYSTABLES].where("TABLE_NAME like ?", "SYS%")
tables.each { |r| puts r[:table_name] }
```

This query takes a stupid long time to run on my machine, but it does return all tables that start with "SYS". The only change I did need to make to my `/etc/odbc.ini` for this to work was to rename the DSN to "default"

```
[default]
Description = IBM i Access ODBC Driver
Driver      = IBM i Access ODBC Driver
System      = my.host.com
UserID      = MYUSERNAME
Password    = MYPASSWORD
Naming      = 1
DefaultLibraries = *usrlibl;
Database    = MYDBNAME
```

Just for anyone else that may run into this issue, here are a few other things I did along the way to get things working. My setup is Ubuntu 14.04

1. Install `unixodbc` and `unixodbc-dev`
2. My `my.host.com` needed to be added to my `/etc/hosts` since it didn't resolve on public DNS.
3. The driver filename I installed is called `ibm-iaccess-1.1.0.4-1.0.amd64.deb`
4. running `ldd /opt/ibm/iaccess/lib64/libcwbodbc.so` showed that there was a missing symlink.`
5. Added missing symlink for `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.1` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2`

That's it. Hope that helps other people too.